# SQL - Teams and Their Player Count

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd need some help here. Im stuck on this SQL Query.

I have 2 Tables team and function. Team contains `ID`,`Teamname`. Function contains `ID`,`Role`

role decides whether a person is a player or a coach (0 for player, 1 for coach).

I am supposed to list all teams that exists, but they should only count players and even teams with no players should be listed to. There's teams that only have coaches for example.

i can't find any way to count everyone within a team.

This is the closest I've come:

```
select teamname, 
       count(*) 
from function left outer join team on team.id = function.id 
WHERE role=0 
group by teamname;
```

Comment: @OP, the query in my answer below is identical to yours, and it seems to be working correctly. Are you trying to get a result that looks like | TEAMNAME | # OF PLAYERS | or something different?

Comment: Yes, im supposed to get an output like that. or 
|# OF PLAYERS|TEAMNAME|

Comment: What is being returned when you run your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to get the result:

```
SELECT t.teamname
     , COUNT(1) AS player_count
  FROM team t
  LEFT
  JOIN function f
    ON f.id = t.id 
   AND f.role = 0   
 GROUP BY t.teamname;
```

-- or --

```
SELECT t.teamname
     , IFNULL(SUM(f.role=0),0) AS player_count
  FROM team t
  LEFT
  JOIN function f
    ON f.id = t.id 
 GROUP BY t.teamname;
```

---

These queries use the `team` table as the driver, so we get rows from `team` even when there isn't a matching row in function. In the first query, we include the role=0 condition as a join predicate, but it's an outer join. In the second query, it's still an outer join, but we only "count" rows that have role=0.

**NOTE** It looks as if something is missing from your model; the `id=id` join predicate looks odd; it's odd that we'd have a column named `id` in the function table which is a foreign key referencing `team.id`.

Normally, `id` is the surrogate primary key in a table, and it's unique in that table. If it were unique in the `function` table, then that implies a one-to-one relationship between `team` and `function`, and the query will never return a count greater than 1.

Again, I strongly suspect that the "member" entity is missing from the model.

What we'd expect is something like this::

```
team
  id         PK
  teamname

member
  id         PK
  team_id    FK references team.id
  role       0=player, 1=coach
```

such that the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT t.teamname 
     , IFNULL(SUM(m.role=0),0) AS player_count
     , IFNULL(SUM(m.role=1),0) AS coach_count
  FROM team t
  LEFT
  JOIN member m
    ON m.team_id = t.id
```

Comment: There is a third table, member. it does conatin ID,name,familyName and birth.

Comment: Thank you! it works great and thank even more for explaining how it works so i could understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can't select a single column when an aggregate function exists in the `SELECT` clause.

To get a count of all rows in the table *and get the name of the team*, you must use only aggregated columns or functions in the `SELECT` clause. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), team.teamname
FROM function LEFT OUTER JOIN team ON team.id = function.id
WHERE function.role = 0
GROUP BY team.teamname
```

Gives you a total of all rows where role is equal to 0 *plus the name of the team*.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  This only shows how many players are in the database, gives no account for which team they are on.

Comment: @paqogomez - Thanks I have updated my answer. EDIT: Just realized this is the same as OP's question. This is working for me so I'm not sure what is happening to OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
SELECT teamname,SUM(IF(role=0,1,0)) players
 FROM function 
 LEFT JOIN team USING (id)
 GROUP BY teamname;
```

This counts only those entries from 'function' that have player role (0).